# Get list of Fields attached to vaadin Form

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a vaadin form with huge number of fields in it(textbox, select box etc..).I need to reset all fields values to null on certain event.

**How can we retrieve a List of Fields attached to vaadin from**. So I iterate run through them and call setValue on each of them to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public List<Field> getAllFields(Form form) {
  Collection<?> propertyIds = form.getItemPropertyIds();
  List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>(propertyIds.size());
  for (Object itemPropertyId : propertyIds) {
    fields.add(form.getField(itemPropertyId));
  }
  return fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a one approach

```
for(Object propertyId : form.getItemPropertyIds()) {
      form.getField(propertyId).setValue(null);
}
```